# TCP/IP Addresses and Subnets

Tags: ip, mask, dhcp, subnet

### TLDR:  Can I use the subnet mask to allow me to put a computer with a static IP address of 192.168.40.1 on my router that has all other computers addressed as 192.168.0.nnn?

Hello all.

This may be a very dumb question, and I apologize in advance.  I did some searching and spent this morning reading articles about this, but something isn't clicking with me.  I hope somebody here can help.

My router is a configured as a DHCP server.  It has the following settings;
IP Range:  192.168.0.151 to 192.168.0.250
Subnet Mask:  255.255.255.0

My printer, NAS, managed switches and wireless access points are configured using a static IP (192.168.0.15 for the switch, 192.168.0.99 for the router, etc, etc.)

It works pretty well.

I want to do some experimenting, though.  I want to hook a new server up to my physical infrastructure and have a work station attach to it, but I want them to have a separate set of IP addresses;
192.168.40.1 for the test server
192.168.40.10 for the test work station

Both still need to have access to the internet through my router at 192.168.0.99

Can I set the subnet mask on my router to; 255.255.0.0 to accommodate this?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that would work.
It will definitely work if you change every device to 192.168/16.

Here's a couple of other possibilities to consider:

- Does your router have more than on port, if so why not configure the second port as the 192.168.40/24 subnet?
- If not, can you configure more than one subnet on a single port -- adding 192.168.40/24 to your existing 192.168.0/24 config.

Comment: Thanks for the response...

Just to get some clarification...  You saying that I need to change devices connected to my network to have a subnet mask of 192.168/16?  I hope not, since in addition to the 10 or so static IP's, there's got to be 50 being served by the DHCP...

The router has four ports (I'm assuming you're talking about physical ports) but I don't see where I can configure them separately.  Also, this would be impractical because I want the new server in the back of the building and the work station at my desk.

Comment: Then I would go with trying your plan and seeing if it works.  If it doesn't, it looks like using a /16 everywhere might be plan B.